# RadioButton as flat button?

Tags: android

Is there a way to style a RadioButton as a flat button? I have four options:

```
| btn1 | btn2 | btn3 | btn4 |
```

instead of having the little radio circle next to each, I'd like to show each as just a plain flat button. Is that possible without having to draw them myself?

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55139080/1318946

Answer (score 26):

Yes it is possible.

In xml set, 
`android:button="@null"`

And in case you want to do it dynamically, `setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can change the drawable used for a radio button.

`android:button` (or `setButtonDrawable`) controls the image used for the circle. Set it to null if you want no image.

You could then set the background of the radio button with `android:background` or `setBackgroundResource` to a normal button-style background.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5821669/612250) for related help. I have been trying to get the "radio circle" to disappear too (which i can get it to work in the xml as shown in my example on the linked page) but it doesn't work if i try to do it dynamically.

Hope this helps and any help on my issue would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Actually setting the button drawable to android's empty resource worked... All i had to do was: myRadioButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.id.empty); myRadioButton.setPadding(5,0,5,0); and then it worked (except for some weird inconsistencies with the Xoom... ie: The Xoom gets a "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File from drawable resource Id #_______" when trying to use the "android.R.id.empty" resource)

Comment: fixed this problem. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997359/android-r-id-empty-broken-in-xoom-honeycomb

Answer (score 0):

Try this segmented control button library on github:
https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol