# android.R.id.empty broken in Xoom/Honeycomb?

Tags: android

I have been trying to make radio buttons without the dot which toggles. I have been successful by doing this:

```
myRadioButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.id.empty);
```

this works fine in all devices before Honeycomb 3.0.x. When I try and use the "empty" resource on the Xoom i get an error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(xxxxx): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from drawable resource ID #0x1020004
```

so, I was wondering if there was a reason why the [empty resource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#empty) suddenly doesn't work on the Xoom. Any help would be appreciated. If you want to take a look at the radioButton related post it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821669/android-dynamic-radiogroup-radiobuttons-as-flat-buttons%20%60here%60)

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are trying to use an id as a drawable. You need to use android.R.color.transparent instead.