# Permanently change resource of ImageButton

Tags: android

I have 3 ImageButtons. I have been trying to change the resource on image button onClick programmatically like when an imagebutton is pressed change the image on it until some other button is not pressed but its not changing. I have used selector for the source:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/favorites02" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/favorites02" />
    <item android:state_hovered="true" android:drawable="@drawable/favorites01" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/favorites00" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And in java in OnClicklistener I am changing resource like this:

```
btnFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isFavchecked = true;
                isAllChecked = false;
                isRecentChecked = false;
                btnFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites02);
                btnRecent.setImageResource(R.drawable.tile_recent_style);
                btnAll.setImageResource(R.drawable.tile_music_style);
            }
        });
```

but it only shows what is declared for the first time.

Comment: Try to use RadioButton instead of ImageButton.

Comment: can we show images on radiobuttons? and how would i hide the checkable circle . makes no sense :S

Comment: yes why not and you also hide checkable circle.

Comment: Try to set this properties  android:button="@null" which can be hide checkable circle and  for background set this properties android:background="@drawable/yourcustomselector".

Comment: @Haresh is right. Radio Buttons are what actually you wanna achieve. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619859/radiobutton-as-flat-button

Comment: I have solved the issue. I applied the selector in the background and changed image of resource. Thanks